# Edit Devise email format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently using devise for user registration and will like to restrict signups based on domains like @company.com or @work.com. The aim is for users to only provide the first part of their email address for example "lucy.dale" then select their domain from a drop-down menu such as @company.com. Please see the code I have generated so far..

```
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_email, :autofocus => true %><%= f.select :domain, options_for_select([["Select One", ""], "@company.com", "@work.com", "@office.com"]) %>
```

As i don't have access to the Devise controller or mailers, please can you advise me on how I can join the :first_email & :domain attributes to give (lucy.dale@company.com) before passing it to the default :email attribute in Devise.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: override the registration_controller, and there override build_resource

Comment: Hi apneadiving. As i am a newbie overiding the controller is a bit tricky. Is there a way to join the :first_email and :domian before passing it to Devise :email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help someone out there. Instead of extending the devise registration controller, i decided to use a Regex to validate the domains. This will allow me restrict the domains as shown below

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@(company\.com)|(work\.com)\z/
```

The regex was added to the model for validation.